# How many pills of each type should a person buy to minimize the price while exceeding the monthly requirements

Tags: word-problem

> A vitamin pill $P$ contains $12$ mg iron and $10$ $mg$ zinc. Another pill $Q$ contains $5$ mg iron and $8$ mg zinc. A person needs $80$ mg iron and $100$ mg zinc each month. Pill $P$ costs $4$ dollars and pill $Q$ costs $3$ dollars. How many pills of each type should a person buy to minimize the price while exceeding the monthly requirements?

I have no idea what to do, any help? (Please keep it as simple as possible, this is from a high school textbook before functions are introduced.)

Comment: First step is to identify the "unknowns" the problem asks you to find.  Pick symbols for those unknowns and write down their definitions (including specification of what units of measurement are involved, where applicable).

Comment: @hardmath right, maybe not that simple. I should be able to solve this but I'm just not used to working with integer equations and inequalities.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use equations, you will have to use trail and error.
Let's see :
Say you buy only *P* pills , need= 10, cost =40.
Only *Q*, need= 16, cost= 48.
Since first one costs less, let us try to minimize it further.
 Take   *P*=9, then *Q* required=2, cost= 42. Take *P*=8,  then *Q* required=3, cost= 41.  Take   *P*=7, then *Q* required=4, cost= 40.  Take   *P*=6, then *Q* required=6 (no. of *Q* increases on account of decreasing iron which is only 5mg per *Q* pill) , cost= 42.From here, if we decrease *P* further, the amount of *Q* required will increase fast because of only 5mg per *Q* pill. So, the conclusion is that the lowest expense is 40 dollars which can be achieved in 2 ways : 1) 10 *P* pills.
2) 7 *P* pills and 4 *Q* pills.

Comment: I would quite like to use equations. I dont want to use functions!

Comment: The equations may contain more than one variable. Are you fine with that?

Comment: absolutely, go nuts!

Comment: @Neutronic Let x= no. of P pills and y= no. of Q pills. Then, 12x+5y>=80 and 10x+8y>=100. Plot these on graph paper and find the common area. Take only integral values from the common area and compare.